# Space padding in a CSV string using regex

Tags: python, regex

In Python, I'm trying to space-pad numbers in a CSV string with regex's.  I can of course do this with split(), format(), and join(), but my constraint is to use a regex.  Why is the following `re.sub` only doing substitutions on found matches 0,2,4,6,8? It's skipping every other match.

```
import re

# trying to pad the single-digit numbers in a CSV with a single leading space
# input '1,2,12,14' would produce output ' 1, 2,12,14' (notice leading spaces on single-digit numbers)

s = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35'
print(s)

# first, add commas to front and end so that first and final numbers are captured by the regex
s = ',' + s + ',' 
# the main regex
s = re.sub(r',([0-9]{1}),', r', \1,', s)
# lastly, strip the front and end commas we added before the regex
s = s.strip(',')
print(s)
```

...above produces the following with input string and output string shown:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35
 0,1, 2,3, 4,5, 6,7, 8,9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35
```

So I'm just curious about the technical reason how `re.sub()` is behaving here.

Comment: That is because the pattern `,([0-9]),` matches a comma, single digit, comma. In this string `,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,` it can only match `,0,` and then `,2,` etc. What would the expected result look like?

Answer (score 2):

You get that result because the pattern `,([0-9]),` matches a comma, single digit, comma. In this string (where you also have prepended the comma) `,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,` it can only match `,0,` and then `,2,` etc...

To pad the single-digit numbers with a single leading space, you could simplify your script leaving out using strip and appending commma's and  using a positive lookahead for the pattern instead.

Note that using the quantifier `{1}` can be omitted.

```
,([0-9])(?=,)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ2q6R/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IXkohE)

For example

```
import re
s = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35'
regex = r',([0-9])(?=,)'
s = re.sub(regex, r', \1', s)
print(s)
```

Output

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35
```

If you also want to support padding only single digits, you could update the positive lookahead at the end match either a comma or assert the end of the string:

```
,([0-9])(?=,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZQmEak/1)

**Edit**

As you also want to append and prepend a comma and pad the first digits as well you could update the pattern to `(?:,|^)([0-9])(?=,|$)`

```
import re

s = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35'
s = ',' + s + ','
s = re.sub(r'(?:,|^)([0-9])(?=,|$)', r', \1', s)
s = s.strip(',')
print(s)
```

Output

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/XPrlpr)

Comment: Simpler regex than my one

Comment: @rob_7cc I have added an update when only having single digits.

Comment: That's exactly what I was reaching for...I rarely (never) use "lookahead" but that was the component that did the trick, here.   Your answer update also fixed the final number being a single digit, but I also need the first digit to be padded.  Trying the lookahead with a comma or beginning of line did not work: `regex = r'(?=,|^)([0-9])(?=,|$)'`.  However, if I use your original regex and keep the prepended and appended commas then it works as desired.  Unless you have a thought about the very first digit?

Comment: @rob_7cc Do you mean like this `(?:,|^)([0-9])(?=,|$)` where you would trim the comma at the start and end https://regex101.com/r/tItjHf/1

Comment: Yes, using that regex example that you posted I would have to prepend and append commas, do the regex, then do a `strip()` ... which is fine.  I'll post my final implementation as an answer since that will allow me to include a code snippet.

Comment: Yes, but it also works with your original simpler regex (with pre- and post- comma steps), so that's what I went with as shown in my answer posted below which incorporates your original regex.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the following regex to acheive what you want to do:

`r'(?<!\d)(\d)(?=,|$)'`

Negative look behind, not a digit: `(?<!\d)`

Matching group any digit: `(\d)`

Postive look ahead comma or end of line: `(?=,|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/UQtqHK/1

```
import re

s = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,5'

print(s)

s = re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(\d)(?=,|$)', r' \1', s)
print(s)
```

That said you might be better off using `str.format()`

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

```
row_one = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13"
row_two = "1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12,13,5,6,7,8"
row_one_array = row_one.split(',')
row_two_array = row_two.split(',')
print(",".join(["{:>2}".format(x) for x in row_one_array]))
print(",".join(["{:>2}".format(x) for x in row_two_array]))
```

The magic bit is: `{:>2}`

`:` = Start term (Not sure what this is called)

`>` = Right align

`2` = Character width

Comment: Thank you...your regex almost works but it does not space-pad a final number if it is single-digit.  Running yours produced: ``` 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,7```.  Thanks for the input but I do prefer the compactness of `The fourthbird`'s answer.  Also, I was intentionally avoiding `format()`, `join()` and `split()`.

Comment: Ah yes, missed the last one will tweak it. My point is that you probably don't need regex at all. Python has built-in functionality for doing this.

Comment: I hadn't read your comment fully. The example was to demo the concept in case you were unfamiliar with it. I wonder if there is a nicer way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is where I ended up, incorporating `The fourth bird`'s regex:

```
s = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,7'
print(s)
s = ',' + s + ',' 
regex = r',([0-9])(?=,|$)'
s = re.sub(regex, r', \1', s)
s = s.strip(',')
print(s)
```

...which gives input string and output string below, as desired:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,7
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35, 7
```

This works for me...thanks to all repsonders!

Comment: I believe my new regex removes the need to append and strip commas, the regex is slightly more complicated not sure if that actually improves performance, but the code would be a little cleaner.